# Self Join in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am having following table data:

```
Company_ID  Parent_Id    Name       SigningGroup
129         109          A          SG1
144         105          B          SG2
```

The output i want to get is below

```
 Company_ID     Parent_Id   Name    SigningGroup
 129            109         A       SG1
 109            NULL        X       SG1
 144            105         B       SG2
 105            NULL        Y       SG2
```

Please help. What will be the query to get the above result.

Comment: Can you format this better please.  It is hard to read.

Comment: @Om: don't mess up other folk's edits please

Comment: Thank you for the formatting it in a table, could you please let me know which option you have used to format it.

Comment: Where do you get the new values for `Name` from?

Comment: Read here about formating your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It can be joined by another table, added to make clear it, that it is different ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a self join because there is nothing to JOIN

You can generate your desired output like this though

```
SELECT Company_ID, Parent_ID, [Name], SigningGroup FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Parent_ID,  NULL,      [Name], SigningGroup FROM MyTable
```

Comment: "This answer is useful" Perhaps not what OP is looking for but with the given test data this is enough.

Comment: It was helpful for me, and i have utilized the same & for the correct name i have joined the output of the Union from another table which contains the details.

Answer (score 1):

select Company_ID,  Parent_Id,   Name,    SigningGroup,
from t
union
select Parent_Id, null,   Name,    SigningGroup
from t

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
; with cte as
(select Company_ID, Parent_Id, Name, SigningGroup
 from my_table
 union all
 select cte.Parent_Id Company_ID, t.Parent_Id, cte.Name, cte.SigningGroup
 from my_table t join cte on cte.Parent_Id = t.Company_ID)
select * from cte
```